How to load local csv files into shinyLive code block within a Quarto document?
I want to create a quarto document that contains a code block that uses shinyLive to run an interactive graph.
At the moment, all the examples I have seen are either:

using R's inbuilt dummy data
or, creating very small data sets themselves within the server function code.

Is there a way to load a local csv data file for the shinyLive code block to use for the interactive visualisation.
Most examples I have seen have asked the user to input the file themselves which is not ideal.
The ideal outcome is to give users the document already rendered without the data set for them to input.

Fairly sure that the answer is a simple no - you can't write an app that has access to local files for security reasons. The only option is to use fileInput
